# Most effective way to split a GUI screen with PySide?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I'm writing a PySide application with a GUI meant for a touch screen. It has a main window that covers 75% of the screen and a 25% vertical panel that has buttons that control the content displayed on the main window (several widgets/screens should appear on the main window).

I've seen several different ways for doing this "split": QFrame, QStackedLayout, QStackedWidget. Being a beginner with PySide/Qt, I couldn't figure out which one is the best way to go for my specific case. Any suggestions or example applications?

Answer (score 4):

QFrame with a QVBoxLayout and specify the stretch factor: (C++ code)

```
MainWidget main = new MainWidget();
ButtonWidget buttons = new ButtonWidget();

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(buttons);
layout->addWidget(main);
layout->setStretch(0,25);
layout->setStretch(1,75);

form->setLayout(layout);
```